# Python - Execute Process -> Block till it exits & Suppress Output

Tags: python, subprocess

I'm using the following to execute a process and hide its output from Python. It's in a loop though, and I need a way to block until the sub process has terminated before moving to the next iteration.

```
subprocess.Popen(["scanx", "--udp", host], stdin=subprocess.PIPE, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use [`subprocess.call()`](http://docs.python.org/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.call). From the docs:

> subprocess.call(*popenargs, **kwargs)
>   Run command with arguments. Wait for command to complete, then
>   return the returncode attribute.
>   The arguments are the same as for the
>   Popen constructor.

**Edit:**

`subprocess.call()` uses [`wait()`](http://docs.python.org/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.Popen.wait), and `wait()` is vulnerable to deadlocks (as Tommy Herbert pointed out). From the docs:

> Warning: This will deadlock if the
>   child process generates enough output
>   to a stdout or stderr pipe such that
>   it blocks waiting for the OS pipe
>   buffer to accept more data. Use
>   communicate() to avoid that.

So if your command generates a lot of output, use [`communicate()`](http://docs.python.org/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.Popen.communicate) instead:

```
p = subprocess.Popen(
    ["scanx", "--udp", host],
    stdin=subprocess.PIPE,
    stdout=subprocess.PIPE,
    stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
out, err = p.communicate()
```

Comment: Unlike poll(), there's a danger of deadlock here.

Comment: if doing this, output will be suppressed. Is there anyway to get output, but still print all output to stdout?

Answer (score 8):

If you don't need output at all you can pass devnull to `stdout` and `stderr`. I don't know if this can make a difference but pass a bufsize. Using devnull now `subprocess.call` doesn't suffer of deadlock anymore

```
import os
import subprocess

null = open(os.devnull, 'w')
subprocess.call(['ls', '-lR'], bufsize=4096, stdout=null, stderr=null)
```

Comment: In my case the "bufsize=x" didn't solve my problem if I was still using "stdout=subprocess.Pipe". But the "stdout=null" worked well. However, python already allows you to use "stdout=None" which can replace your null variable that is a bit useless here. ;)

Comment: It is not the same, "...With None, no redirection will occur; the child’s file handles will be inherited from the parent..." insted usign my example you are redirecting all the output to a null device.